# How do i remove a Child that is Added and Defined in a Separate Function? (AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3

I currently have the Code:

```
function timerHandlerR(e:TimerEvent):void{
if(RedTargetAdded){
    removeChild(RedTarget);
}
randomXR = Math.random()*500;
randomYR = Math.random()*300;
RedTarget.x = randomXR;
RedTarget.y = randomYR;
addChild(RedTarget);
RedTargetAdded = true;
RedTarget.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandlerR);
tween = new Tween(RedTarget, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 0, 1, 3, true);
}

function clickHandlerR(e:Event):void{
var mySound:Sound = new Shooting(); 
mySound.play();
var breaking:Sound = new Break(); 
breaking.play();
points ++;
points_txt.text = points.toString();
removeChild(RedTarget);
}
```

However when trying to remove the child RedTarget within the clickHandlerR function it returns an error stating that it cannot as the object RedTarget is not a child of the caller. Is there any easy way to fix this.

PS. i have tried parent.removeChild(parent.child) and that did not work (unless i did it incorrectly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because of this block of code:

```
if(RedTargetAdded){
    removeChild(RedTarget);
}
```

You have this var, called `RedTargetAdded`. You set it to `true` when you add `RedTarget`, but you **don't** set it to `false` when you remove `RedTarget`

So the next time `timerHandlerR` runs, it tries to remove `RedTarget` again (event though it was already removed) because that var is still `true`.

As an aside, you don't need to define a var to store whether the item is added or not,  just check the `parent` property.

```
//use this instead of the code above, and get rid of RedTargetAdded all together
if(RedTarget && RedTarget.parent){
    removeChild(RedTarget);
}
```

Although, there seems to be no point in that block of code at all as you're just adding RedTarget again no matter what right below that block.

Comment: That code works like the previous code i have used, the issue being that the child is removed, but then cannot be added back as the child has now been removed from timerHandlerR, with the error message being:
ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.
 at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/removeChild()
 at TargetShootingGame_Targets_fla::MainTimeline/timerHandlerR()
 at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
 at flash.utils::Timer/tick()

Comment: that error message is very helpful.  I'll update the answer.

Comment: That makes so much sense, thankyou for the code and explanation everything is working perfectly now, ill remember to ask my questions here before i spend a day and a half looking for alternative methods and solutions xD. Again, thankyou very much!